# curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: curl, https, .net-core

I am trying to install the .net Core SDK 2.0.0 on Centos 7 following the directions in "[.NET Tutorial - Hello World in 5 minutes](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxcentos)".

When I ran the first command

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

I got this error:

```
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
error: https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc: import read failed(2)
```

I am behind a corporate proxy, and it seems this error is related to SSL certificate and curl, but I don't know how to fix it.

Also, I get a similar error when I use curl or wget to download the HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue and then just temporary turned off SSL check and installed the packages. But please be warned that this is bypassing a security measure so use with caution.

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.conf
```

And then on the editor just add the following line

```
sslverify=false
```

Comment: Worked like gem for me. Thanks.

Comment: I needed sslverify=0 instead

Answer (score 30):

Finally fixed it. Posting the answer here as reference.

- Get a copy of the company trusted root certificate
- If it's not in PEM format, convert it. (e.g. for DER run `openssl x509 -in xxx.cer -inform der -outform pem -out xxx.pem`)
- Install the ca-certificates package: `yum install ca-certificates`
- Enable the dynamic CA configuration feature: `update-ca-trust force-enable`
- Place the root certificate in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
- Run `update-ca-trust extract` to add the root to the system's trusted certificates

References:

https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

http://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html

Comment: how did you know you had to convert them to .pem?  The link you referenced makes it look like you can add the .crt and update the CA store, nothing about converting.

Comment: Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)". We need to know what it is about those links that is useful. Without that, *when* the links rot and die they'll make no sense, possibly making your answer make no sense; At this point the first link is dead. And, while answering a question yourself is a good thing, please be sure to describe *why* the answer is the correct solution. If that can't be done, then please select the most helpful answer instead.

Comment: @theTinMan this is hardly a link-only answer. It provides a detailed set of steps to follow, with the links clearly identified as source material.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your server has valid proxy settings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This doesn't seem to answer the OP, and could be posted as a comment. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: For my current problem, actually this was the most useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The self-signed SSL certificate I was using had expired so on Cent OS 7 I run the command below, but increased the days from `-days 365` to  `-days 1400`, which is approximately a 4 year guarantee.

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
```

You can find more information in "[How To Create an SSL Certificate on Apache for CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7)".

Comment: Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)"

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for centoS 6. Here is how I fixed it:

Step 1: Open /etc/yum.conf for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.conf
```

Step 2: Add this line below [main]

```
sslverify=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by installing the site certificate in the trust store.

Assuming you have a copy of the certificate named _.example.com.cer, you can run the following commands:

```
$ sudo yum install -y ca-certificates
$ sudo cp _.example.com.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
$ sudo update-ca-trust
```

I ran these commands on a RHEL server (v7.9).
I downloaded the certificate file from the browser. In Chrome, when you view the certificate, you can export it under the Details tab.

Reference: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem
mv tls-ca-bundle.pem tls-ca-bundle.pem.back
wget --no-check-certificate https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem
mv cacert.pem tls-ca-bundle.pem
```